# How to add tuple in argparse for the pipeline in AzureML?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tuples, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to `argparse` tuple for the function which I execute in the pipeline. For simplicity I will just skip steps with reading data and other which are not that much related to the topic. This looks like this:

```py
def model_train_sales(X_train, order: tuple, seasonal_order: tuple):

    model = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(X_train['sales'], order=order, seasonal_order=seasonal_order)
    results = model.fit()

    return model, results

def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument("--order", type=tuple)
    parser.add_argument("--seasonal_order", type=tuple)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    model, results = model_train_sales(X_train['sales'], order=args.order, 
    seasonal_order=args.seasonal_order)
```

At this moment everything is fine, but when you start building pipeline types of parsed variables are different.

```py
from azure.ai.ml import command
from azure.ai.ml import Input, Output

demo_model_training_component = command(
    name='my sarima pipeline',
    display_name='my description',
    description='A long description.',
    inputs={
        "order": Input(type='<TYPE>'),
        "seasonal_order": Input(type='<TYPE>'),
    },
    outputs=dict(
        df = Output(type="uri_folder", mode="rw_mount")
    ),
    code = feature_creation_src_dir,
    command = """python sarima_model.py \
              --order ${{inputs.order}} --seasonal_order ${{inputs.seasonal_order}} \
              --df ${{outputs.df}}
              """,
    environment = f"{pipeline_job_env.name}"{pipeline_job_env.version}",
)
```

Here I signed `<TYPE>` the place where I'm not sure which type should be. I know that types are limited, it is either `string`, `integer`, `number` or `bool`.

Is there any way to parse tuple within? Or the only way around is to parse `p, d, q` and `P, D, Q, S` separately and combine them into tuple within the main function?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a `tuple` type object, only `Input`, `dict`, `str`, `bool`, `int`, and `float` are supported.

However, you can pass it as a string and convert it to a tuple in `main.py`.

Give it as a string in the main function.

```
def model_train_sales(X_train, order: tuple, seasonal_order: tuple):

    model = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(X_train['sales'], order=order, seasonal_order=seasonal_order)
    results = model.fit()

    return model, results

def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument("--order", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--seasonal_order", type=str)
    
    print("\n")
    print("------------------------------------------------\n")
    result_tuple = tuple(args.order.split(','))
    print(result_tuple)
    print("\n")
    print("------------------------------------------------\n")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    model, results = model_train_sales(X_train['sales'], order=args.order, 
    seasonal_order=args.seasonal_order)
```

Next, pass it as a string with comma-separated values in the command job.

```
from azure.ai.ml import command
from azure.ai.ml import Input, Output

demo_model_training_component = command(
    name='my sarima pipeline',
    display_name='my description',
    description='A long description.',
    inputs={
        "order": "p,d,q",
        "seasonal_order": "P,D,Q,S",
    },
    outputs=dict(
        df = Output(type="uri_folder", mode="rw_mount")
    ),
    code = feature_creation_src_dir,
    command = """python sarima_model.py \
              --order ${{inputs.order}} --seasonal_order ${{inputs.seasonal_order}} \
              --df ${{outputs.df}}
              """,
    environment = f"{pipeline_job_env.name}"{pipeline_job_env.version}",
)
```

Output:

[image: corrected image description]

and

[image: corrected image description]